# How to implement plain search bar in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I want to remove border for default search bar and implement plain search bar. See image below

Default search bar,

[image: Default Search Bar]

This is what I am trying to achieve,

[image: Plain Search bar]

I googled and tried below code but does not achieve the desired effect,

```
for (id img in searchbar.subviews) 
{
    if ([img isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) 
    {
        [img removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

searchbar.delegate = self;
searchbar.layer.borderWidth = 0;
searchbar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Have you tried this under iOS 7? By default there is no border around the `UISearchBar`.

Comment: No, I did not tried with IOS 7 as I am using IOS 6. I will check above code with IOS 7 also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answers. I have solved my problem using below code....

[image: Plain White Search bar background image used in the below code]

```
UITextField *txfSearchField = [self.searchbar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
        [txfSearchField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [txfSearchField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
        [txfSearchField setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
        [txfSearchField setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbar_bgImg.png"]];
        [txfSearchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
        //txfSearchField.layer.borderWidth = 8.0f;
        //txfSearchField.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
        txfSearchField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        txfSearchField.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeNever;

        [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT" size:20]];
        [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 there is a small change, now you have to iterated two levels.

```
 for (UIView *subView in self.searchBar.subViews){
    for (UIView *2ndLeveSubView in subView.subViews){
    if ([2ndLevelSubView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")])
        {
            [2ndLevelSubView removeFromSuperView];
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: I tried your code but the expected output is not came...Thanq for ur answer.